# Select username from other table, if NULL

Tags: mysql

How to select the row entry from an `users` table, if the other table has an `NULL` value?

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT(`fh_users`.`username`, '_', `fh_ftp_user`.`username`) AS `userid`,
    `fh_ftp_user`.`password` AS `passwd`,
    '1010' AS `uid`,
    '1010' AS `gid`,
    `fh_ftp_user`.`path` AS `homedir`,
    '/sbin/nologin' AS `shell`
FROM
    `fh_ftp_user`,
    `fh_users`
WHERE
    `fh_ftp_user`.`username`='%U'
    OR
    (`fh_ftp_user`.`user_id`=`fh_users`.`id` AND `fh_users`.`username`='%U' AND `fh_ftp_user`.`username` IS NULL)"
```

Implicit, the table `fh_ftp_user` will be selected. `fh_users` will only used to `CONCAT` the username with the main username.

**User Table**

[image]

**FTP Users**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

**Expected result**

If `fh_ftp_user.username` is `NULL`, set `fh_users.username` as `userid`
otherwise, if `fh_ftp_user.username` is **not** `NULL`, concat both usernames with an underscore as `userid`.

How i can create here an sub-query to handle these behavior?

Comment: Sounds like your are looking for `COALESCE` more or less like `COALESCE( fh_users.username, CONCAT(...))`   safer option is using CONCAT_WS instead which is null safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) you can handle the situation:

```
 SELECT
     CASE WHEN fh_ftp_user.username IS NULL THEN fh_users.username
          ELSE CONCAT(`fh_users`.`username`, '_', `fh_ftp_user`.`username`) 
          END AS `userid`,
     ....
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) returns `NULL` if anny of the values is `NULL`